# AWS lambda - how to know the event format from AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

## Question

How to know the event format coming to Lambda from AWS services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS Lambda console includes a **Test** function, which can provide a sample event for most of the events that are generated by AWS.

You can **modify** these sample events to include your specific data.

For example, the `Amazon S3 Put` sample event simulates a new object being added to an Amazon S3 bucket. You can modify the event to **include your own Bucket and Object names**, then use it to test the function without actually using Amazon S3.

Comment: >You can modify these sample events to include your specific data.
Can we actually do this? Looks the data is static, and there is no steps to change the sample data in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/test-drive-firehose.html#test-drive-destination-s3.

Comment: Your link is referencing the ability for Amazon Kinesis Firehose to generate a "fake" stream of data for testing the processing of a stream. My answer above is referring to the **Test** button in the AWS Lambda console. If this does not suit your purposes, please update your question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

[Generating Sample Event Payloads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-generate-event.html)

```
$ sam local generate-event --help
Usage: sam local generate-event [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  You can use this command to generate sample payloads from different event
  sources such as S3, API Gateway, and SNS. These payloads contain the
  information that the event sources send to your Lambda functions.

Commands:
  alexa-skills-kit
  alexa-smart-home
  apigateway
  batch
  cloudformation
  cloudfront
  cloudwatch
  codecommit
  codepipeline
  cognito
  config
  connect
  dynamodb
  kinesis
  lex
  rekognition
  s3
  sagemaker
  ses
  sns
  sqs
  stepfunctions
```

### S3 put

```
$ sam local generate-event s3 put
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789",
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "example-bucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "test/key",
          "size": 1024,
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### Firehose

```
$ sam local generate-event kinesis kinesis-firehose
{
  "invocationId": "invocationIdExample",
  "deliveryStreamArn": "arn:aws:kinesis:EXAMPLE",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "records": [
    {
      "recordId": "49546986683135544286507457936321625675700192471156785154",
      "approximateArrivalTimestamp": 1495072949453,
      "data": "SGVsbG8sIHRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0IDEyMy4="
    }
  ]
}
```

---

## Update

As per the comment by @John Rotenstein, Lambda console can generate much more sample events.

[image]

For Go lang, [aws-lambda-go/events/](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/tree/master/events), provides a list of sample codes showing how to handle events from different sources and sample [test data](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/tree/master/events/testdata). Good resource to have a look.

Comment: That's nice. +1. Very useful for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Just print it out the first time you start your development. For python, the command is:

```
print(json.dumps(event))
```

The output should be available in CloudWatch log group for your lambda. This is must useful for debugging and testing with real-live events.

Sometimes, in documentation you can also find it. But I found that just printing it out is the fastest and most reliable way to get to know the `event` format.